# Co-occur colors of outfit, SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have a data Table, two columns

[image: DATA TABLE]

How would I write code in SQL that shows the top two co-occuring colors. So the output should be a table with two columns (color and count) . ex "Green","Red" 3, "Blue" "Blue" 2, "Pink" "Purple" 1. I'm working with a big dataset so I would want something a little simpler to use.

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2014. I'm pretty new to it, I've tried using COUNT to get the number of times each time the color occurs, however i'm stuck on how to go within the name and count combinations.

Comment: My pseudocode:
1. Check to see all combinations of colors.
2. Add all combinations of colors to new column
3. If combination exits, add +1 to it's count
4. In new person, if combination does not exist, add to column
5. Sort By Count

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare @t table (
    person varchar(100),
    color varchar(100)
);

insert into @t values
('Bob', 'Green'),
('Bob', 'Red'),
('Mark', 'Blue'),
('Mark', 'Blue'),
('Sally', 'Pink'),
('Sally', 'Purple'),
('Kat', 'Green'),
('Kat', 'Red'),
('Mike', 'Green'),
('Mike', 'Red'),
('Pat', 'Blue'),
('Pat', 'Blue');

with t as (
    select
        t.*,
        row_number() over (partition by person order by color) rn
    from @t t
)
select 
    t1.color color1, 
    t2.color color2,  
    count(*) cnt
from t t1 inner join t t2
on t1.person = t2.person
and t1.rn > t2.rn
group by t1.color, t2.color
order by cnt desc;
```

Produces:

[image]

Comment: THIS WORKS perfectly Thanks

Comment: only edit i'll need to make is instead of creating the table, just loading it in and going from there